# Инициализация констант angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Здравствуйте, я новичок в angular, подскажите пожалуйста, как мне инициализировать константы в самом начале работы приложения. Сейчас они иницилизируются в блоке resolve роутера, но это не вариант, придётся для каждого роута писть один и тот же резолв. Так же если конттроллер вложе в другой, то родительский не увидит данных которые резолвит дочерний.

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', {
                controller: 'AppCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    initConstants: function($rootScope, $q, $location) {
                        console.log('start resovling');
                        var deffered = $q.defer();

                        if ($rootScope.CONSTANTS){
                            console.log('constants already resolved!!!');
                            deffered.resolve();
                            return deffered.promise;
                        }

                        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                            '{!$RemoteAction.MobileController.getConstants}',
                            function(result, event) {
                                if (event.status){
                                    var jsonStr = result.replace(/&quot\;/g, '"');
                                    $rootScope.CONSTANTS = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
                                    deffered.resolve();
                                    console.log('constants resolved!!!');

                                    $location.path('/MyLearning');
                                } else{
                                    console.error('loadConstants - error!');
                                    console.error(event);
                                    deffered.reject(event);
                                }                                 
                        });

                        return deffered.promise;     
                    }
                }                
            }).otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/'
        });
    });
```

Хотелость бы как-нибудт инициализировать их в методе run, но как это сделать через promis не знаю

Comment: каких ещё констант ? в js это понятие отсутствует и в angular тоже ничего такого нет. когда мне подобное было нужно я просто поместил весь темплейт с остальным приложением в ng-if.

Comment: константы в angular есть http://habrahabr.ru/post/190342/

Comment: вопрос не в константах, а в том как мне до формирования контроллеров и страницы получить данные с сервера

Comment: щас, найду пример я как-то делал

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q6iZf2A1RA4jKVCxdOY8?p=preview

Comment: https://github.com/philippd/angular-deferred-bootstrap